# RxJS, Observable, how to preserve value and switch map to another one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

```
// ticker$ will update every 3s
// showHand$ will only triger after user click button
// I would like to take last ticker price as user order price when user click button

let lastPrice: number;

this.ticker$
  // What I am doing now is preserve value to vairable here.
  .do(ticker => lastPrice = ticker.closePrice)
  .switchMap(() => this.showHand$)
  .subscribe(showHand => {
     // use value here
     this.order.price = lastPrice;
     this.order.amount = showHand.amount;
     this.order.type = showHand.type;

     this.submit();
  });
```

Any segestion about how to prevser value and switch map together, without one line variable like above?

Comment: Please consider changing the accepted answer to the result selector solution posted by Cameron. There is no need to use another operator and withLatestFrom has certain caveats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is the operator

```
this.showHand$.take(1)
  .withLatestFrom(this.ticker$)
  .subscribe(([showHand, ticker]) => {
    this.order.price = ticker.closePrice;
    this.order.amount = showHand.amount;
    this.order.type = showHand.type;
    this.submit();      
  });
```

Note, take(1) will close subscription, but if you want the user to be able to press the button many times, save the subscription to a const and unsubscribe when finished.

Comment: what does take(1) do?

Comment: take(n) limits the number of items from showHand$ and emits complete() after n items. A complete on this should automatically stop the subscription.

Answer (score 15):

Results selector function is deprecated in version 6 will be removed in version 7.

From docs:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#result-selectors

**with resultSelector (v5.x)**

```
source.pipe(
 switchMap(fn1, fn2)
)
```

**the same functionality without resultSelector, achieved with inner map**

```
source.pipe(
 switchMap((a, i) => fn1(a, i).pipe(
   map((b, ii) => fn2(a, b, i, ii))
 )
)
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `withLatestFrom()` has certain caveats when subscribing late that this solution doesn't have.

Comment: The second example here (`switchMap` with inner `map`) worked great for me!

Answer (score 7):

The behaviour you require is already possible with an overload of [`SwitchMap`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-switchMap) with a selectorFunc for the combination of every `(outerValue,innerValue)`:

```
this.ticker$
  .switchMap(
    () => this.showHand$,
    (tickerValue, switchMap) => tickerValue
  )
  .subscribe(showHand => { });
```

Comment: someone should make an article about this resultSelectorFunction

Comment: resultSelector is deprecated since rxjs 6

Answer (score 5):

There is a little hack to achieve this - basically you have a whole new observable inside the switchmap, and this observable has access to the value passed into the switchmap function. You can use this value in an inner map to preserve the value.

```
this.ticker$
  .switchMap(ticker => this.showHand$.pipe(map(hand => ({ ticker,hand }) ))
  .subscribe( obj => {
     // use value here
     this.order.price = obj.ticker;
     this.order.amount = obj.hand.amount;
     this.order.type = obj.hand.type;

     this.submit();
  });
```

Comment: Syntax correction: "pipe(map(hand => ({ ticker,hand }) ))