# Angular - How to prevent nested piping with dependent observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In order to keep my code clean I try to prevent nested piping when it comes to observables. However I encountered a constellation (see code below) where I could not find a way to do without. I wonder if there is a way to solve this problem with only one pipe?

Example code:

```
class CannotSimplify {

  observableA(): Observable<number> {
    return of(1);
  }

  bDependentA(a: number): Observable<number> {
    return of(2 + a, 3 + a);
  }

  cDependentOnAAndB(a: number, b: number): Observable<number> {
    return of(a + b);
  }

  printResult(): void {
    this.observableA()
      .pipe(
        switchMap(a => this.bDependentA(a)),
        switchMap(b => this.cDependentOnAAndB(a, b)) // <-- error: a is undefined
      )
      .subscribe(c => console.log(c));
  }

}
```

The only solution I could think of is to pipe `this.bDependentOnA()` again.
Is there a better approach?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't know why but the first lineof my post is somehow left out... I actually wrote "Hi!" but it vanished; I didn't mean to be rude. :)

Comment: I don't think that's possible any more. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397864/rxjs-observable-how-to-preserve-value-and-switch-map-to-another-one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use the [`zip`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/zip) operator for this.

```js
this.observableA()
   .pipe(
     switchMap(a => zip(of(a), this.bDependentA(a))),
     switchMap(([a, b]) => this.cDependentOnAAndB(a, b))
   )
```

As of RxJs version 7, the **zip operator** will be replaced with `zipWith`. More on that [here](https://dev.to/cartant/rxjs-typing-zipwith-15km).

```js
this.observableA()
   .pipe(
     switchMap(a => this.bDependentA(a).pipe(zipWith(of(a)))),
     switchMap(([b, a]) => this.cDependentOnAAndB(a, b))
   )
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This answer almost does the job. However, when bDependentOnA() emits twice (I just edited my question in order to cover this case) then the behaviour differs from the nested piping: with zip() there is one output and with nested piping there are two outputs... Do you now how to solve this edge case?

Comment: I don't see any updates on the question.. :D, but I'd assume it's because of how `zip` works. If you have `zip(a$, b$)`, in order for zip to emit, `a$` and `b$` must create a _pair_. If `a$` emits and then `b$` emits, a pair is created, but then if `b$` emits again and `a$` hadn't, there is no pair! You can read more about it [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/rxjs-operators-for-dummies-forkjoin-zip-combinelatest-withlatestfrom#toc-zip-the-love-birds-operator).

Comment: I see; thank you very much. However, for readibility's sake I will stick with the nested piping then. :D

Comment: @vencint you can use `combineLatest` instead of `zip` to emit every time `bDependentA` emits.

Comment: Yup, that fixes it. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to call three functions within one pipe. It's my solution is to use [zip](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/zip).

```
import { Observable, of, Subscription, zip } from 'rxjs';


    printResult(): void {
        this.observableA()
        .pipe(
           switchMap(a => zip(of(a), this.bDependentA(a))),
           switchMap(([a, b]) => this.cDependentOnAAndB(a, b))
        ).subscribe(c => console.log(c));
    }
```

My example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4ipoen