# Retain values from rxjs operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a subject defined as below

```js
this.checkListSubject
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this._unSubscribeAll),
    filter((filter) => !!filter),
    switchMap((index) => this._api.get('getMyData')),
    tap((list) => this.gateEditArrayModal.toArray()[index].display(list))
  )
  .subscribe();
```

As I understand the tap cannot have the value of index because its lost after switchMap. There is any way to get the value of index in tap?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RxJS, Observable, how to preserve value and switch map to another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46397864/rxjs-observable-how-to-preserve-value-and-switch-map-to-another-one) But not the accepted answer, but this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68283692/5105949 solves your problem. or at least will give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you need to use a nested pipe. In the pipe you map the result into the original index together with the result

```
switchMap(index => this._api.get( 'getMyData' ).pipe(
    map(result => ({result, index}))
)),
// use the index
tap(({index}) => this.gateEditArrayModal.toArray()[index].display()),
// back to the result
map(({result}) => result),
```

Comment: then I loose what is returned from the api. My api returns an array which I want to use in display function. I have edited the question

Comment: you weren't using it in the question. it is easily kept

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that in different ways using other RxJS operators, such as [map](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) or [withLatestFrom](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/withLatestFrom).

1. Using the `withLatestFrom` operator instead of `switchMap`:

```js
this.checkListSubject
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this._unSubscribeAll),
    filter((filter) => !!filter),
    withLatestFrom(this._api.get('getMyData')),
    tap(([index, list]) =>
      this.gateEditArrayModal.toArray()[index].display(list)
    )
  )
  .subscribe();
```

2. Using the `map` operator with `switchMap`:

```js
this.checkListSubject
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this._unSubscribeAll),
    filter((filter) => !!filter),
    switchMap((index) =>
      this._api.get('getMyData').pipe(map((list) => [index, list]))
    ),
    tap(([index, list]) =>
      this.gateEditArrayModal.toArray()[index].display(list)
    )
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: This gave me an error 'index unknown'

Comment: Where exactly, please?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by

```
this.checkListSubject
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this._unSubscribeAll),
    filter((filter) => !!filter),
    switchMap((index) => this._api.get('getMyData')),
    tap((list) => this.gateEditArrayModal.toArray([this.checkListSubject.value].display(list))
  )
  .subscribe();
```